# Is there a 3DSLAM package for ros-hydro?

Tags: ros, 3d-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was looking to do 3d pointcloud construction using a kinect, but i was unable to find and suitable package for the same.
If someone would be kind enough to suggest something.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164366/is-there-a-3dslam-package-for-ros-hydro?/) by [hgtc-dp](https://answers.ros.org/users/15556/hgtc-dp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should state your problem more precisely.

Did you consider [OctoMap](http://octomap.github.io/) or [RGBDSLAM](http://wiki.ros.org/rgbdslam) ?

You may find something relevant at http://openslam.org/ though it may not yet be available as a ROS package.

---

Originally posted by [slivingston](https://answers.ros.org/users/829/slivingston/) with karma: 254 on 2014-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1